# joomla 3. back end administrator login not working - continue loop

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

joomla backend administrator login panel not working. if entered with correct username and password it just loops(it just refresh). 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI1S8.png)

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to mainly two factors i.e sessions and plugins

1. if you try to increase the session time in your global configuration settings to a much higher value like 99999999 you will face this issue. The solution will be to edit your configuration file to change to a reasonable value like 1500 or 3600 etc for a localhost server.

   public $lifetime = '1500';
2. if none of your authentication plugins are enabled you will still face the same issue. So you have to login to phpmyadmin. Go to your Joomla database and find `#__extensions`. There you search for authentication plugin `plg_authentication_joomla`. Enable the Joomla authentication plugin i.e change enabled from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are many causes for this problem, such as:

- A hacked website
- Wrong tmp/log paths in the configuration.php file
- A disabled authentication user/plugin